# jQuery Variable does not hide

Tags: jquery, variables

Here's my code:

```
   $('#details').hover(function() {
    var tag = 'div.cds'
    var offset = $(this).position();
    var width = $(tag).outerWidth();
    var height = $(tag).outerHeight();
    $(tag).show();
    $(tag).css('left', offset.left - width + 'px');
    $(tag).css('top', offset.top - height + 'px');
}, function() {
    $(tag).hide();
});
```

When I "mouseout", the variable "tag" does not hide.

JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/79kLc/

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Learn about `scope`

```
var tag = 'div.cds'
 $('#details').hover(function() {
    var offset = $(this).position();
    var width = $(tag).outerWidth();
    var height = $(tag).outerHeight();
    $(tag).show();
    $(tag).css('left', offset.left - width + 'px');
    $(tag).css('top', offset.top - height + 'px');
}, function() {
    $(tag).hide();
});
```

The `tag` variable did not exist in the second function's scope. So i added `tag` to the global scope. and it should work now.

Comment: @milimetric, i was not tring to be mean :-P

Comment: Both these answers are correct. @Naveed's solution works best for my needs since I re-use the function multiple times and do not need to declare global vars for each function. But @Neal replied first so I'm accepting that one. Thanks to everyone however!

Answer (score 0):

Because `tag` can't be referred in this scope. You'll have to use the selector again. Like this: `$('div.cds').hide();`

Update fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/79kLc/1/